# Can Hellish Rebuke be cast twice with an Action Point for twice the damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, warlock, powers, damage

4e’s Hellish Rebuke:

> 1d6 + Constitution modifier fire damage. The first
>   time you take damage before the end of your next turn, the target
>   takes an extra 1d6 + Constitution modifier fire damage.

If a warlock successfully casts Hellish Rebuke on a creature, spends an action point, and successfully casts it again, and then takes damage before the end of their next turn, does the target take the extra damage once, or twice?

Answer (score 1):

## Twice

The general rule is that two ongoing effects of the same type do not stack but you take the best one.

> Rules Compendium, page 224
>
> Same Type of Ongoing Damage: If a creature is subject to multiple instances of ongoing damage of the same type at the same type (including no type), only the highest number applies.
> Example: If a creature is taking ongoing 5 damage (which has no type) when a power causes it to take ongoing 10 damage, the creature is now taking ongoing 10 damage, not 15.

But we are not dealing with ongoing damage in this case so the rule would not apply, Therefore the 2 effects will just happen sequentially/simultaneous and apply them both.

See also [do-multiple-effects-of-the-same-power-stack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47073/do-multiple-effects-of-the-same-power-stack)

Comment: did some extra research because I was not certain (to many systems in my head) so I looked for the rule as above and precedence on the site